# Symfony2 Adding Recaptcha to FOSUserBundle Login Page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, recaptcha

I am trying to add reCaptcha to the login for for one of my websites.

I have checked out several different reCaptcha bundles and ended up using this one.

https://github.com/dmishh/RecaptchaBundle

Adding to the registration form is easy.

However adding recaptcha to the login form proved much more difficult than I hoped.

Following the instruction on the github page I add the required lines to SecurityController.php:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }

    if ($error) {
        // TODO: this is a potential security risk (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9523)
        $error = $error->getMessage();
    }
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);


    $csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider')
        ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
        : null;


    $recaptcha = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.recaptcha'));

    return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        'recaptcha' => $recaptcha->createView()
    ));
}
```

But just get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::createForm()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SecurityController extends ContainerAware and not Controller.

Replace

```
$this->createForm(
```

By

```
$this->container->get('form.factory')->create(
```